# How to select a row based on what a cell within the row contains using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook that has conditional formatting in it, and it will be a shared workbook. Because I don't want to have to redo the conditional formatting each time data is transferred, I am trying to create a Macro that transfers data to a different sheet within the workbook based on whether a condition is met.

As it is currently written, if value is marked "yes" the table filters by that value and runs a copy/paste/clearcontents...then some aesthetic organization stuff. The macro works great....if the "Yes" is in row 7. I need to expand to the whole table and/or select a row throughout the table if "yes" is found in the column [J].

Is there a better way to write this, or make it work? I had a good class on VB....15 years ago, so I am trying to blow the dust off that section in my mind.

```
Sheets("Current Tasks").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    "Yes"
Rows("7:7").Select
Range("F7").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Completed Tasks").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed Tasks").ListObjects("Table14").Sort. _
    SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed Tasks").ListObjects("Table14").Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table14[[#All],[Deadline]]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed Tasks").ListObjects("Table14").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Sheets("Current Tasks").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10
```

EDIT:  Attached screen shot of project.

[image: screen shot of project]

Comment: you could loop through each row, and perform a task (copy the data to a new sheet) if the value in column 7 = yes.

Comment: Attached a screen shot of some of what I am trying to do. From my understanding I have the "complete" column with a drop down that only allows "yes." This is to be my unique identifier to transfer the data, but again, if there may be a better way to accomplish this. There is no other code, but there is conditional formatting from basic excel formulas to accomplish that. Which is why I dont want to leave it open for everyone to just do the transfer, so the formulas arent changed or lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok hi my dude - I've edited it a little but this should work

```
Sub MoveProjects()

Dim current As Worksheet
Dim complete As Worksheet
Dim table1 As ListObject
Dim table14 As ListObject

Set current = Worksheets("Current Tasks")
Set complete = Worksheets("Complete Tasks")
Set table1 = current.ListObjects("Table1")
Set table14 = complete.ListObjects("Table14")


table1.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Yes"


current.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Copy

  complete.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

  ' there are 2 "End" statements because 1 doesnt work for excel tables, if you want it pasted over the top of your data in the "Complete" sheet then just use complete.Range("A2").Pastespecial xlPasteValues

  Application.CutCopyMode = False


With complete.ListObjects("Table14").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
current.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Delete 'Clears the sheets data
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
table1.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8

End Sub
```

Assign this sub to your button - you may need to edit some values
So the field numbers for the sorts may need changing
Some of the variable names depending on what you've named your columns etc

But this macro will work - it will copy and paste the rows with "YES" and then delete these YES rows from your "Current" worksheet

It pastes them into the "Complete" worksheet on the first empty row

Comment: This worked great. I have one follow question @JacobCrux If i want to keep the conditional formatting built into the excel table, is there a way to just clear text from a cell rather than .delete? I tried .clear as well, but that removes the conditional formatting and the data validation drop downs that were built in? Thank you

Comment: Hi Jared - apologies for the 4 month late reply, you can use "ClearContents" instead, this shouldnt delete any conditional formatting. But it will leave gaps in your table

Answer (score 0):

A few tips for vba
Try to refrain from using .Select and .Activate - great for learning vba via macro recording, but handling your ranges and sheets via Variables is much easier and cleaner

```
Dim current As Worksheet
Dim complete As Worksheet
Set current = Worksheets("Current Tasks")
Set complete = Worksheets("Complete Tasks")
current.ListObjects(table1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    "Yes"

'You could also store the table as a variable and act on it directly


Dim table1 As ListObject
Set table1 = current.ListObjects("Table1")
'So then it looks like this instead
    table1.Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
            "Yes"

'Choose one or the other - work off the worksheet or the ListObject - personal preference in my opinion is to work off the table variable for shorter code
'Same with the ranges, act on a variable to clean out the code

current.UsedRange.Offset(-1,0).Copy

'there are many ways to declare where you want to paste - I'm assuming its in the first cell but change this to your preference
  complete.Range("A1").paste
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

'you could set table14 as a ListObject here and just use 
'With table14.Sort. _ SortFields

With complete.ListObjects("Table14").Sort. _ SortFields
  .Clear
  .Add Key:=Range("Table14[[#All],[Deadline]]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
End With

With complete.ListObjects("Table14").Sort     
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

current.Cells.Clear 'Clears the sheets data 
table1.Range.AutoFilter Field:=10
```

Now I believe all these will make your code much easier to read and work with

For helping your solution could you paste a screen of the table and what you're wanting to expect - also is there any other code?

```
Rows("7:7").Select
Range("F7").Activate
```

I think this is the problem code in question

Comment: My other question is, and it may not be something you can answer, what is the significance of F7? I dont understand why that cell is referenced. If it was something from recording the Macro, or if there is significance to this as a point. To my knowledge there is nothing of direct importance in that cell.

Comment: Ahh I think this is where my confusion is stemming from - It seems there is a command recorded in the macro where it selects the 7th row

Comment: Im going to edit my code to see if I can add in what you want